# SignalIR Hubs in asp.net retaining variables

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am learning signalIR, and have struck an issue. If you have a look at this page there is an example:

https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/asp.net/tracking-online-users-with-signalr/

in the example, you can see the author uses the following methods to track online users:

```
private static int _userCount = 0;

// Overridable hub methods
public override Task OnConnected()
{
   _userCount ++;
}
public override Task OnReconnected()
{
    _userCount ++;
}
public override Task OnDisconnected(bool stopCalled)
{
   _userCount --;
}
```

My issue with this code, is every time any method in this class is called, all the variables are being reset, so every time OnConnected() is called, _userCount starts as 0, then increments to 1. the next time someone connects _userCount is 0 again and increments back to 1 again.

I have another method to check how many users are connected:

```
    public int countUsers()
    {
        return _userCount;
    }
```

This always returns 0

Do I need to store the variables somewhere else serverside?

Answer (score 0):

I found that despite the example using:

```
private static int _userCount = 0;
```

I had used

```
private int _userCount = 0;
```

making the variable static resolved the issue. Thanks to mxmissile for pointing me in the right direction.